# Приём multipart/mixed в angularjs по мере поступления частей

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multipart

Не найду в документации и в поиске такой сценарий работы.
Клиент отправляет одну или несколько команд в одном запросе, а сервер отвечает по мере выполнения несколькими сообщениями.

Для этого подходят типы multipart/*.
Сервер запишет сообщения мультипартом, разделённые по boundary.
Клиент будет выводить данные по мере поступления.
Хочется чтоб на каждую часть ответа выполнился калбак.

Вэб-сокеты знаю, но — нет.

Например [у гугла есть такое апи](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/batch)

Пример взаимодействия ( у гугла в примере немного другое, но представление ответа анологично )

Отрпавляю запрос POST на свой сервер. В ответ получается:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=batch_pK7JBAk73-E=_AA5eFwv4m2Q=

--batch_pK7JBAk73-E=_AA5eFwv4m2Q=
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: <response-1>

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{
 "id":1,
 "data": "data1"
}

--batch_pK7JBAk73-E=_AA5eFwv4m2Q=
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: <response-2>

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{
 id: 2,
 data: "data2"
}

--batch_pK7JBAk73-E=_AA5eFwv4m2Q=
```

и так много `response` в течении 15-30 минут. Возможна и другая инкапсуляция.

Хочется чтоб на каждый ответ внутри большого выполнялся callback в яваскрипте. Как `.then(successCallback, errorCallback)`. Вот только then выполнится когда запрос HTTP закончится.

Работа с вложенными HTTP или с простыми вложениями вроде mjpeg стримов интересна.

EventSource интересно, но он реконектится в конце стрима. Мне же нужно запрос-ответ.

Comment: [Http Long Polling](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2014-12-01-http-long-polling/)

Comment: @vihtor это один запрос и один ответ конекте. мне другое нужно.

Comment: multipart говорит о том что тело запроса состоит из нескольких частей. Сервер всегда отвечает 1 раз. И ответ у гугла в 1 раз приходит. Читайте документацию "The server's response is a single standard HTTP response with a multipart/mixed content type" Там же даже пример есть.

Comment: @IgorGolovin один ответ хттп в котором лежат несколько ответов апи.

Comment: По HTTP протоколу отправляется 1 запрос и получается на него ровно 1 ответ, после чего соединение закрывается. Вам нужен другой протокол или long polling.

Comment: А логнполинг это не хттп? ещё скажите что вэбсокет это не хттп.
Вы ссылку-то читали? вот даже скопировал кусочек для примера в сам вопрос. Соединение одно, но ответов в мультипарте можно много получать. А ещё современные браузеры умеею кипэлайв, но это немного другая история.

Comment: HTTP и websoket это два разных протокола, никак не связанных между собой. Да, они оба реализованы поверх TCP, но это не значит что это одно и тоже. Long polling вообще не является протоколом, поэтому по определению не может быть тем же самым что и HTTP. В гугл апи словом `response` они называют данные, находящиеся между разделителями (boundary). Их может быть много. Ответ сервера в доках называется `HTTP response` и он только один. В  `HTTP response` содержится несколько `response` т.е. данных.

Comment: эта вся философия не относится к сути вопроса. есть же конкретный пример, давай отталкиваться от него. ещё раз повторю: суть мультипарта в том что несколько ответов хттп вкладываются в один.

Comment: эта вся философия не относится к сути вопроса. есть же конкретный пример, давай отталкиваться от него. ещё раз повторю: суть мультипарта в том что несколько ответов хттп вкладываются в один.

Comment: oboe интересная штука, но только для json.

Comment: А как вы будите в течении 15-30 минут отправить http-ответ, если вам перед началом отправки нужно знать длину всего ответа (т.к. она указывается в заголовках в начале ответа)?

Comment: Мне не нужно знать длину ответа. Контент-лен нужна для докачки статики и только. Остальное можно стримить.

Comment: Вот посмотри пример. Контент тайп в хидерах и всё.